# How to use Linq To Sql query to show the data in my case?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

i have a trouble to write a query with Linq i explain better my case, i have a database with 2 tables as follow :

it is the first table ;

- **Hotel**
- HotelID (Nvarchar(10)  - PK)
- HotelName (Nvarchar (200))

and this one is the second table ;

- **Period**
- PeriodID (Int (inc) - PK)
- _From (Datetime )
- _To (Datetime)
- HotelID(Nvarchar(10)  - FK)

then in the second Table (Period) there is the FK (HotelID) to connect the 2 tables;
Happen sometime i have a HotelName that gets more periods(PeriodID) so my purpose is to show the data in an only one Row into a DataGrid, i show  you an example as i want show the data in my DataGrid  if there are more periods in the same HotelName:

| HotelName   |  From  |  To   |  From(2) | To(2)  | From(3) | To(3)  | From(4)|  To(4) |

---

| Excelsior   |12/5/10 |3/6/10 |  2/8/10  | 9/9/10 | 23/9/10 | 1/10/10| 2/11/11| 1/12/10|

so i ask do you have any idea/suggest about how to show the data in a DataGrid inside one Row using Linq To Sql ?

thanks so much for your attention .

Have a good time .

Cheers

Comment: Off topic: Don't let your PK be a `VARCHAR`. Let it be an `INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)`. If your users need a unique name, you can add that with a unique constraint, but don't let it be the primary key in your table. This is bad for performance and obscures development.

Comment: @Steven, thanks so much friend for your suggestion , i will correct it as your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article explains working with hierarchical data binding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478959.aspx

Then, create an object model which roughly maps to your database tables:

```
Hotel
 - ID
 - Name
 - Bookings
  - Booking 1 { From, To }
  - Booking 2 { From, To }
  - Booking n { From, To }
```

Your Linq should look something like this:

```
var hotels = _db.Hotel.Select();

foreach(var hotel in hotels)
    hotel.Bookings = _db.Period.Where(x => x.HotelId == hotel.HotelId).Select();
```

Comment: Hi christofr , i read about your link ,i will try to follow this step and let you know ,thanks so much.